# How to make a smooth navigation that will highlight the place where the user is?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There is such a smooth page navigation.  How do I add the "current" class to the navigation menu, depending on where the user is now?  So that when a person gradually turns the mouse, a section of the site in the navigation menu is displayed to him.
https://jsfiddle.net/sazdan/h9rske5p/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let target  = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });

});
```

---

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <h2 id="one">One</h2>
    <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="two">Two</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <h2 id="three">Three</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="four">Four</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="five">Five</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="six">Six</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

<aside>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="current" href="#one">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
        <li><a href="#six">Six</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highlight item in an index, based on currently visible content during scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958471/highlight-item-in-an-index-based-on-currently-visible-content-during-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if this is what you're trying to achieve, but you can place a `scroll` event in `window` to calculate which `h2` is within screen bounds and set the `current` class to the respective `a`:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  $('h2').each(function(){
    let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
    if(elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom){
      $('aside a').removeClass('current');
      $('aside a[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('current');
    }
  });
});
```

Add this inside `$(document).ready()`.

You can check this [article](https://medium.com/talk-like/detecting-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-jquery-a6a4405a3ea2) on how to detect if an element is on screen.